# Getting a value in ViewController from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to get the value in ViewController from AppDelegate, but I am not able to do so.

I have only one ViewController. I tried to make the value as a constant or variable. None of them works.

I am not sure if this is the correct approach, but I tried to use rootViewController to access.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    var test:String = "test"   
  // let test = "test" 
  }
}
```

in AppDelegate

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let viewController = self.window?.rootViewController as? ViewController
    print("from_viewC \(String(describing: viewController?.test)))")
}
```

Comment: I see that the `test` variable is local variable. How can you access a local variable outside of its scope ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare the variable outside of `viewWillAppear` to make it accessible from outside:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  var test = "test"

  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    // whatever is in here...
  }

}
```

Comment: When I do that, I get nil, but no error. Why is that?

Comment: Maybe because `self.window?.rootViewController as? ViewController` is nil; is your view controller in a navigation controller or tab bar controller?

Comment: You do not get error because you have used Optional operator "?" (referred to as safe unboxing).

Answer (score 0):

Set windows root view controller like this:

```
self.window.rootViewController = ViewController()
```

Than you can access your value as you are doing above. Also you have to make test variable a class member before you can compile.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you try to access rootViewController's variable inside didFinishLaunchingWithOptions? What is your exact requirement?

DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions is the point where your rootViewController will get allocated!

You can try inside didEnterBackground, didEnterForeground, didBecomeActive delegate functions in appDelegate to access the rootViewController's variable!